# Hopf equation with Non-differentiable initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to solve the Hopf equation (preferably with the method of characteristics)  $$u_t + uu_{x}=0$$ with initial condition $$f(x) =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1- |x|  &, |x| \leq 1 \\
     0 &, |x| \geq 1\\
\end{array} 
\right.  $$

Using the method of characteristics we can easily find $$ u=f(x-ut)$$
Thus we have 
$$u =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1- x+ut &, x-ut \geq 0 \\
     0 +x - ut &, x-ut \leq 0\\
\end{array} 
\right.  $$
but it doesn't seem like I can solve this to get $u$ as a function only of $x,t$ and not $u$ itself. Any ideas?

Additionaly, I would like to find the breaking time $t_b$ and breaking point $x_b$, which doesn't require analytically solving the problem, just finding the characteristics, which are: $$x=f(ξ)t +ξ $$ 
Now if $f$ where differentiable we would have $ξ_x =\frac{1}{f'(ξ)t+1}$ and thus the breaking time would be at $t$ such that $f'(ξ)t+1=0$, which gives $t_b=1$ if we ignore the $x \in (-1,0)$ part (since breaking wont happen where $f'(x) >0$). Is this correct? Also what is the breaking point, since  $f'(ξ)t+1=0$ at $t=1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Why doesn't it 'seem like I can solve this to get $u$ as a function only of $x,t$ and not $u$ itself'? $$u = 1-x+ut \implies u(1-t) = 1-x \implies u = \frac{1-x}{1-t}$$ I'll let you change the inequality condition accordingly. Can you see how this relates to the breaking time?